# Read a CSV file and split values in java

Tags: java, csv, filereader

Hello I want to read a file.csv that contains word pairs like this

```
1 AA 9877.88,BY US,SA 6785.66,....
```

I want to split that data in below format

```
9877.88,US,6785.66,.........
```

I have written below lines of code to read csv file

```
do{
    currentline = br.readline()
    
    if(currentline != null)
    {
    
    arrayStrFileRows = currentline.split(",");
}
```

can anyone please help me to arrange data according to the requirement. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of parsing CSV and read [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section to embed it properly here. Which library do you use?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow useing java.io and java.util lib

Comment: Cool, that is why I try to help you to learn how the good question should look like. Not only it is easier for other people to investigate problem and provide solution but also it assures you that they will provide the solution which will fit to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Next time i ll keep in mind 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting your line by COMMA, split each field in that row by SPACE and take the last element.

```
currentline = br.readline()
… for each line of input 
List< String > newFields= new ArrayList<>() ;
String[] fieldsOfRow = currentline.split(",");
for( String field : fieldsOfRow )
{
    String[] partsOfField = field.split( " " ) ;
    String lastPart = partsOfField[ partsOfField.length - 1 ] ;
    newFields.add( lastPart ) ;
    …
}
String newLine = String.join( "," , newFields ) ;
```

Comment: Yes its working but the problem is it removed COMMA as well. Now the data i am getting 9877.88US6785.66......... but i want 9877.88,US,6785.66,......... COMMA as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NewScholar I’m confused. Your own code would append the commas when you put together the desired pieces. See my added code. Or better, use a CSV library such as *Apache Commons CSV* to assist.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It's working pretty well 

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but it looks like you may want to further split the string you have inside your string array, arrayStrFileRows, by the white space and append the values you need to a new string you ll print.

```
arrayStrFileRows = currentline.split(",");
String result ="";

for (int i=0; i<arrayStrFileRows.length(); i++){
    String[] tokens = arrayStrFileRows.split(" ");
    if (i ==0){
         result = tokens[2]    //i m not too sure about this since there are 3 words/numbers before your first comma and is the 1 supposed to be there or not?
    }else{
         result = result +","+token[1];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1 is a part of first string

Comment: Can you please check this line its showing compile time error

Comment: then it must be there is a syntax error some where. I think i forgot to add a semicolon on result = tokens[2];

Comment: what is your arrayStrFileRows exactly? If it is a string it should be able to be .split() I m basing it off the code you provided

Comment: arrayStrFileRows its string array. Thank you for your help

Comment: Then you need a for loop to iterate through each line of the string array, and for each string, split(",") , it and then split it again by " ".